# Exponential decay 'proof' that $.\overline{9}\neq 1$?

Tags: proof-verification, exponential-function, fake-proofs

I have doubts about $.\overline{9}$ being equal to 1 due to the following proof:

> To get a decimal containing $c$ 9's after the decimal point, the equation f(c) = $1-10^{-c}$ can be used.
>
> For example, f(3) = $1-10^{-3} = 1 - .001 = .999$
>
> With this function, $.\overline{9}$ (or a number containing infinite 9's after the decimal point) can be modeled by $f(\infty)$. This also makes $.\overline{9} = f(\infty)$
>
> This, of course, cannot be evaluated directly. No attempts will be made to perform arithmetic operations using infinity.
>
> To model the difference between 1 and a number with a varying amount of nines, this equation can be used:
>
> $1 - f(c)$
>
> This can be simplified as follows:
>
> $1 - (1 - (10^{-c}))$
>
> $1 - (1 - 10^{-c})$
>
> $1 - 1 + 10^{-c}$
>
> $10^{-c}$
>
> This clearly follows the format of an exponential decay function. This means that the original function of $1 - f(c)$ also follows the rules of exponential decay.
>
> There are two main properties of exponential decay functions relative to this proof:
>
> > 1. the domain stretches from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$
> > 2. the asymptote is 0 (that is, it approaches but never reaches 0)
>
> Since this function does not reach 0, even at infinite bounds, that would mean that $1 - f(\infty) \neq 0$
>
> From here, $f(\infty)$ can be replaced with $.\overline{9}$ as shown before. The equation becomes $1 - .\overline{9} \neq 0$
>
> A final simplification by adding $.\overline{9}$ to both sides yields:
>
> $1 \neq  .\overline{9}$

This seems to refute many $.\overline{9} = 1$ proofs, but not having an extensive math education, I do not know if there is anything wrong with the proof. It seems as if there may be something very wrong with the proof, as basically everyone agrees that $.\overline{9} = 1$. Is there a problem, and if so, what?

Comment: Let $x = 0.999...$. Then $10x - x = 9.999... - 0.999... = 9$ thus $x=0.999...$ :)

Comment: Yes, I have seen that proof. It seems fairly watertight, but I am wondering what makes this particular proof wrong. Only one statement can be true, so I would like definite proof that one of them is wrong to be able to consider the other fully right.

Comment: I guess it depends on how you define addition and subtraction. What does $0.999...$ really mean? For example, consider the subtraction $\dots 4321 - \dots 5432$.

Comment: The problem I see immediately is the vague use of $\infty$. $f(\infty)=10^{-\infty}=\frac{1}{10^\infty}$ which is kind of ill defined. I think you need a more rigorous notion of a limit, and also infinity

Comment: The conclusion is wrong. The author shows that for no finite $c$ can $1-f(c)=0$ and concludes that $1-f(\infty)\ne 0$.

Comment: The proof is self-contradictory because in lines 6-7 you said "No attempts will be made to perform arithmetic operations using infinity" and then in line 22 you said "$1-f(\infty)\ne0$", which is an attempt to do arithmetic with infinity.

Comment: It is not doing an arithmetic operation, because it is not adding, subtracting, multiplying, dividing, etc. but instead using algebraic properties. (e.g. exponential decay functions never reach 0) In other words, it is not performing arithmetic on infinity because it is not attempting to solve for what value $1-f(\infty)$ might be. It is just manipulating it with algebra.

Comment: I'd recommend that whoever wrote that 'proof' should take a basic analysis class. @CodeCube Before looking at any of these 'proofs' can you answer to yourself what does $0.999\dots$ even mean?

Comment: A key idea to take away from this is that, loosely speaking, predicates and limits don’t always “commute.” I.e., if a statement holds for all members $x$ of a set, it might not hold for the set’s supremum/infimum, as in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement beginning "Since this function does not reach 0, even at infinite bounds..." is nonsensical. That's one big flaw in the "proof" since your entire conclusion hinges on it.

In fact, exactly the opposite is true:
$$\lim_{n \to\infty}(1-f(n)) =0$$

Comment: But isn't that a property of exponential decay functions? They have an asymptote of 0, so they can never reach it, right?

Comment: Not in finite time. But they decay to zero nonetheless, meaning the limiting value is zero.

Comment: Hm, I have not encountered this before. Could you name the division of math where this is shown? I would be interested in learning more about it.

Comment: Calculus and analysis.

Comment: @MPW I'd recommend avoiding saying things like "not in finite time". Unless you want to add the symbol $\infty$ to your domain, this gives a false intuition about $\lim$s, in my opinion.

Comment: Note that the "limiting value" $L$ is not necessarily a value that is ever assumed. It just means that actual values $f(x)$ get closer and closer to that value $L$ as $x$ grows larger and larger (i.e., that $f(x)\to L$ as $x\to\infty$). I suppose I would call this precalculus or basic analysis.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: I was speaking in the context of an asymptote as OP mentioned. Besides, one usually uses symbols such as "$x\to\infty$" without ever intending for "$\infty$" to become part of the domain, right?

Comment: ah, okay! This makes much more sense now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You have shown that the difference between $1$ and $f(c)$ is $10^{-c}$. This leads to the following "exchange":

I claim that $1 = 0.\overline{9}$. You say no, this is not the case: we have $1 \ne 0.\overline{9}$. In fact, we have $1 > 0.\overline{9}$. We can write this alternatively as:
$$
1 = 0.\overline{9} + \varepsilon
$$
for some nonzero $\varepsilon$.

But I can find a $c > 0$ so that $1 - f(c) < \varepsilon$. This is easy, because
$$
1 - f(c) = 10^{-c},
$$
so if I take $c > - \log \varepsilon$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
-c &< \log \varepsilon \\
10^{-c} &< \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Why is this bad? Notice:
\begin{align*}
10^{-c} &< \varepsilon \\
1 - (1 - 10^{-c}) &< \varepsilon \\
1 - f(c) &< \varepsilon \\
1 &< f(c) + \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
But you claimed that $1 = 0.\overline{9} + \varepsilon$, which clearly contradicts the last line!

---

This is the problem. You're right when you say that $10^{-c}$ is positive for all $c$. However, no matter what, $10^{-c}$ can be forced to be smaller than any choice of offset (in the proof above, this was what $\varepsilon$ represents). $10^{-c}$ is *eventually* smaller than every positive real number. So as $c \to \infty$, $10^{-c} \to 0$, because $0$ is smaller than every positive real number. As a consequence, $f(c) \to 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You either accept that you can treat infinity as a value or you do not. It is true that $10^{-c}>0$ for all finite $c$. That said, we may make $10^{-c}$ as close to $0$ as desired by taking sufficiently large $c$. In particular, if you *do* choose to give $f(+\infty)$ any relevant meaning, it must be that $f(+\infty)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $0.\overline{9}$ equals anything it must equal $1$. To see this we will use the $f$ given in the proof, i.e. $f(n)=1-10^{-n}$. As stated in the proof, for a given $n$, $f(n)=\underbrace{.9999...9}_{n \text{ times}}$

Since $10^{-n}\gt 0$ for all $n$, $f(n)\lt 1$ and so $.\overline{9}\le 1$. But for any real number $r\lt 1$ we can find $m$ large enough so that $f(m)=\underbrace{.9999...9}_{m \text{ times}}\gt r$. Since we can do that for all $r\lt 1$, it follows that $0.\overline{9}\ge 1$

Therefore, $0.\overline{9} = 1$